# How to bevel edges without distorting the mesh?

Tags: modeling, bevel

[image]

[image]

I want to bevel outer edges of that hole. But it results in distorted object.
I have tried improving topology but it does not work.

Here is blend file
[image]

Comment: Hello :). I can see multiple possible reasons from your images. Please upload your .blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can take a look.

Comment: @JachymMichal Done! : )

Comment: Hello. It was caused by flipped normals. Select all vertices and go to *Mesh->Normals->Recalculate* Outside. Then it will work just fine. CGMatter ecplains more here https://youtu.be/Z--dnYonag0